# Hierarchical SQL query for products

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table for products with the same concept as shown below:

```
items|component
A    |A1
B1   |B4
B    |B2
B    |B1
B2   |B4
B    |B3
```

I need a SQL query that will show the results:

```
items|level|component
A    |1    |A1
A1   |2    |
B    |1    |B1
B    |1    |B2
B    |1    |B3
B1   |2    |B4
B2   |2    |B4
B3   |2    |
B4   |3    |
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what have you tried?  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please explain the logic of your output

Comment: I didn't understand why would B1, B2, B3 have the same level? Could you please share the logic?

Comment: Actually, I saw many videos explaining hierarchical SQL queries, but I found that didn't serve what I'm looking for.

Comment: As you can see in the first table there are items an their components. What I'm looking for is to be organized in such a way the item will be in the top and its components to be under it and so on for other items.   @Avi

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur because all of them are components for B.

Comment: and to get the level for each so I can distinguish where is the item and its components. @Avi

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
drop table t1;
create table t1 (item varchar2 (10), component varchar2 (10));
insert into t1 values ('A' ,'A1');
insert into t1 values ('B' ,'B1');
insert into t1 values ('B' ,'B2');
insert into t1 values ('B' ,'B3');
insert into t1 values ('B1' ,'B4');
insert into t1 values ('B2' ,'B4');
commit;

select item, level, component from t1 connect by item=prior component;
```

If you really want to add those components that missing from the items list to the items, in this case SQL might look like this:

```
select item, level, component 
from t1 
connect by item=prior component
union all 
select distinct component,1,null from t1 where component not in (select item from t1);
```

Comment: The missing components are never at level 1.

Comment: I'd say they shouldn't be there at all, since they're missing as items or I don't really understand the case in question.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef26bc/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_names ( items, component ) AS
SELECT 'A',  'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'B4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2', 'B4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  'B3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT LEVEL, t.*
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table_names
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           component, NULL
    FROM   table_names
    WHERE  component NOT IN ( SELECT items FROM table_names )
  )
) t
START WITH items NOT IN ( SELECT component FROM table_names )
CONNECT BY PRIOR component = items
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef26bc/10/0)**:

```
| LEVEL | ITEMS | COMPONENT |
|-------|-------|-----------|
|     1 |     A |        A1 |
|     2 |    A1 |    (null) |
|     1 |     B |        B1 |
|     2 |    B1 |        B4 |
|     3 |    B4 |    (null) |
|     1 |     B |        B2 |
|     2 |    B2 |        B4 |
|     3 |    B4 |    (null) |
|     1 |     B |        B3 |
|     2 |    B3 |    (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT LEVEL, t.*
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table_names
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           component, NULL
    FROM   table_names
    WHERE  component NOT IN ( SELECT items FROM table_names )
  )
) t
START WITH items NOT IN ( SELECT component FROM table_names )
CONNECT BY PRIOR component = items
ORDER BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT( items ), LEVEL, items
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef26bc/10/1)**:

```
| LEVEL | ITEMS | COMPONENT |
|-------|-------|-----------|
|     1 |     A |        A1 |
|     2 |    A1 |    (null) |
|     1 |     B |        B3 |
|     1 |     B |        B1 |
|     1 |     B |        B2 |
|     2 |    B1 |        B4 |
|     2 |    B2 |        B4 |
|     2 |    B3 |    (null) |
|     3 |    B4 |    (null) |
|     3 |    B4 |    (null) |
```